# Hiding php code from URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there I can hide the PHP information in the URL without reloading the page?

I have the current HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="get">
    <label>
        <input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="3 characters minimum" name="url" class="urlinput" type="text">
    </label>
    <input name="submit" class="urlsub" type="submit">
</form>
```

And when I click submit this happens

> http://example.com/?url=example&submit=Submit

Is there any way I can keep it as example.com while the information still passes to php?

Full code:

```
 <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <label>
            <input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="3 characters minimum" name="url" class="urlinput" type="text">
        </label>
        <input name="submit" class="urlsub" type="submit">
</form>
<?php
IF($_POST['submit']) {
    include('include/functions.php');

    // IP OF THE USER
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // URL TO PUT IN Database
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    // MAKE SIMPLE URL EG: HTTPS://WWW.GOOGLE.COM -> GOOGLE.COM
    $surl = surl($url);
    // RUN SCRIPT
    CIURLE($surl, $ip);
}
?>
```

Comment: With ajax you can. See [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)...

Comment: Instead of GET use POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from using GET method to using POST method

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
 <label>
  <input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="3 characters minimum" name="url" class="urlinput" type="text">
  </label>
  <input name="submit" class="urlsub" type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
  echo 'Posted url: '.$_POST['url'] . '<br>';
  echo 'Remote IP:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean not work? This is function of the browser not your code.

Comment: When I do it I have to submit twice. Ill share my code by editing the post.

Comment: If you edited your code then clicked the button that was already loaded. That form was still doing a get. From the previous code.

Comment: I ran your code. After commenting out your include and custom functions it ran with no problem.

Comment: After reading the code again, it seems like it's a problem with a function but thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use "POST" instead of "GET". It's explained in the link.

http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. It looks like POST is exactly what OP needs to use. If he wants the form to submit in the background without causing a page change, then he'll need AJAX.

Comment: @Spencer Don't know either and thank you for recognizing it.

Comment: Just to clear things up -- I didn't downvote. It was probably someone else.

Comment: @ErroR Everything you need to know is in the link.